# Retain newlines in standard report exports

Tags: reporting

I have a field that has a number of line breaks in it, and I want to have the field exported with the line breaks retained in a report. The fields themselves should look something like this

```
Full name, Title, \r\n
Full name, Title, \r\n
```

I used a trigger to populate the field, and simply added on the \r\n to the end of the "Full name, Title" string. When I tried to export the report using the "export details" button, the new lines are forgotten about, and the xls document shows this:

```
Full name, Title, \r\nFull name, Title, \r\n
```

Which is not what I want. I tried using the "printable view" button, but all that did was separate the cell into multiple cells according to the line breaks, which rendered it unusable.

What I'd like to know is whether or not there is an alternative to '\r\n' that I can put into the field, such that the "export details" button will keep the line breaks, and what this alternative is.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using only \n ?

Comment: It may be as simple as highlighting the cells in Excel and clicking "Wrap Text."  I believe excel displays all contents on one line, even if there are line breaks, unless that option is selected.

Comment: @e-bacho2.0, I did and it didn't change anything. I was thinking that maybe the carriage return would have caused the problem, but sadly, no.

Comment: @Benj, no go on that one--the text was already wrapping.

Comment: Too bad.  Looks like there's an old idea on the ideaexchange to fix this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007DRw

Comment: I've found that resource earlier today, but I'm wondering exactly what I should do with it? That is, where should I be putting this code? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Unless you're going to write your own report export Visualforce page, the code in the comments you found is of no use to you. There is no way to patch the standard export to Excel feature such that it will work. Salesforce.com has to fix this. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Export to Excel" XLS format is actually an HTML file disguised with an XLS ending (so that your computer will automatically open the file in Excel instead of a web browser). HTML, by its very nature, usually collapses multiple whitespaces into a single whitespace. For example, given the following HTML:

```
<p>The Quick Brown
        Fox Jumps Over
   The Lazy Dog</p>
```

Will be rendered as:

The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog

Since HTML doesn't insert line breaks as a matter of course (except for very specific conditions), there is usually a tag that is used known as the break tag (`<br/>`). This instructs an HTML parser to insert a literal line break at the indicated position.

Getting back to Excel, when its HTML parser observes a line break, it will ignore it, just as it is supposed to. That means that if your source looks like:

```
<td>John Doe
Jane Doe
Mary Jane</td>
```

Excel will dutifully render it as:

```
John Doe Jane Doe Mary Jane
```

To fix this, salesforce.com would need to patch their export engine to change `\n` into a `<br/>`. You cannot insert a literal `<br/>`, because it would be encoded as `&lt;br/&gt;`, which Excel would render back into `<br/>` upon HTML parsing.

The current workaround is to *export as CSV*. CSV honors whitespace and is therefore suitable for properly exporting line delimited data. You should note that this will strip all formatting from the file, but retain the line breaks.